# How to get access to job parameters from ItemReader, in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

This is part of my `job.xml`:

```
<job id="foo" job-repository="job-repository">
  <step id="bar">
    <tasklet transaction-manager="transaction-manager">
      <chunk commit-interval="1"
        reader="foo-reader" writer="foo-writer"
      />
    </tasklet>
  </step>
</job>
```

This is the item reader:

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component("foo-reader")
public final class MyReader implements ItemReader<MyData> {
  @Override
  public MyData read() throws Exception {
    //...
  }
  @Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}")
  public void setFileName(final String name) {
    //...
  }
}
```

This is what Spring Batch is saying in runtime:

```
Field or property 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of 
type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

What's wrong here? Where I can read more about these mechanisms in Spring 3.0?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As was stated, your reader needs to be 'step' scoped. You can accomplish this via the `@Scope("step")` annotation. It should work for you if you add that annotation to your reader, like the following:

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("foo-reader")
@Scope("step")
public final class MyReader implements ItemReader<MyData> {
  @Override
  public MyData read() throws Exception {
    //...
  }

  @Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}")
  public void setFileName(final String name) {
    //...
  }
}
```

This scope is not available by default, but will be if you are using the `batch` XML namespace. If you are not, adding the following to your Spring configuration will make the scope available, per the [Spring Batch documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />
```

Comment: `StepScope` is now available by default

Comment: There's also a shortcut since v2.2 using [@StepScope](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/StepScope.html) with @Bean

Comment: `@Scope("step")` didn't work for me, whereas `@StepScope` did

Comment: Spring doesn't really like final classes

Comment: we can annotate the @StepScope on method

Answer (score 34):

If you want to define your [`ItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html) instance and your [`Step`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/Step.html) instance in a single JavaConfig class. You can use the [`@StepScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/StepScope.html) and the [`@Value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotations such as:

```
@Configuration
public class ContributionCardBatchConfiguration {

   private static final String WILL_BE_INJECTED = null;

   @Bean
   @StepScope
   public FlatFileItemReader<ContributionCard> contributionCardReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}")String contributionCardCsvFileName){

     ....
   }

   @Bean
   Step ingestContributionCardStep(ItemReader<ContributionCard> reader){
         return stepBuilderFactory.get("ingestContributionCardStep")
                 .<ContributionCard, ContributionCard>chunk(1)
                 .reader(contributionCardReader(WILL_BE_INJECTED))
                 .writer(contributionCardWriter())
                 .build();
    }
}
```

The trick is to pass a null value to the itemReader since it will be injected through the `@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}")` annotation.

Thanks to Tobias Flohre for his article : [Spring Batch 2.2 – JavaConfig Part 2: JobParameters, ExecutionContext and StepScope](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/06/spring-batch-2-2-javaconfig-part-2-jobparameters-executioncontext-and-stepscope/)

Comment: How will we test this?

Answer (score 21):

Pretty late, but you can also do this by annotating a @BeforeStep method:

```
@BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobParameters parameters = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobParameters();
        //use your parameters
}
```

Comment: This is only useful, if the usage of the job-parameters are *not altering the state* of the ItemReader. If they are e.g. used to designate what data to read, then concurrent execution of the reader might cause incorrect behaviour.

Comment: @tveon, this can be solved by using StepScope when declaring the reader bean, right?

Comment: @Kajzer yes, and unless you reuse the reader later in the same job, then you can also solve it with `JobScope`

Answer (score 14):

To be able to use the jobParameters I think you need to define your reader as scope 'step', but I am not sure if you can do it using annotations.

Using xml-config it would go like this:

```
<bean id="foo-readers" scope="step"
  class="...MyReader">
  <property name="fileName" value="#{jobExecutionContext['fileName']}" />
</bean>
```

See further at the [Spring Batch documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope).

Perhaps it works by using `@Scope` and defining the step scope in your xml-config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />
```

Comment: I'm interested in annotations specifically. This format of configuration is old and documented.

Comment: You haven't stated that you were interested in an annotations-only solution only. Thanks for the vote anyhow.

Answer (score 5):

Complement with an additional example, you can access all job parameters in JavaConfig class:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemStreamReader<GenericMessage> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters}") Map<String,Object> jobParameters){
          ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While executing the job we need to pass Job parameters as follows:

```
JobParameters jobParameters= new JobParametersBuilder().addString("file.name", "filename.txt").toJobParameters();   
JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

by using the expression language we can import the value as follows:

```
 #{jobParameters['file.name']}
```

Answer (score 1):

'technical' writing.

configuration class.

```java
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testReader")
    private testReader reader;


    @Bean(name = "testJob")
    public Job testJob(@Autowired @Qualifier("testStep") Step step) {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("testJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
//                .listener(new JobCompletionListener())
                .start(step)
                .build();

    }

    @Bean("testStep")
    @JobScope
    public Step testStep(@Value("#{jobParameters['key']}") String key) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("testStep")
                .<UniqueUserVO, List<UniqueUser>>chunk(500)
                .reader(reader.setKey(key).reader())
                .processor(processor.processor())
                .writer(writer.writer())
                .build();

    }
```

reader interface class.

```java
public interface Reader<T> {

    /**
     * reader 
     * @return
     */
    ItemReader<T> reader();
}
```

reader class

```java
@Component
public class TestReader implements Reader<UniqueUserVO> {
    private String key;

    public TestReader setKey(String key) {
        this.key= key;
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public ItemReader<UniqueUserVO> reader() {
       xxxxx
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a scenario where you need to access JobParameters in an ItemWriter or ItemReader to set values like the file path for writing. In this case, you can utilize a [JobParameterExecutionContextCopyListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk_bkp/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/JobParameterExecutionContextCopyListener.html).

Suppose you have a non-bean class where you create your STEP reader/writer. You can then create a [JobParameterExecutionContextCopyListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk_bkp/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/JobParameterExecutionContextCopyListener.html) and specify the keys you want to extract, like *myDate*:

```
private TaskletStep internalBuild() {
    try {
        JobParameterExecutionContextCopyListener listener = new JobParameterExecutionContextCopyListener();
        listener.setKeys(new String []{"myDate"});
        return new StepBuilder("MY_STEP", jobRepository)
                .<T, T>chunk(batchSize, transactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .processor(new PassThroughItemProcessor<>())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .listener(listener)
                .build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new SqlToCsvException(e);
    }
}
```

Next, in your writer (e.g., FlatFileItemWriter), if you want to set the resource based on the date obtained from the JobParameters, you can override the open method to handle this logic:

```
    public FlatFileItemWriter itemWriter() {
    FlatFileItemWriter writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<T>(){
        // Override the resource given from the executionContext.
        @Override
        public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
            this.setResource(new FileSystemResource(getMyFileNameFromDate((LocalDate) executionContext.get("myDate"))));
            super.open(executionContext);
        }
    };

    // Other configurations for the writer...

    return writer;
}
```

This approach allows you to dynamically set the resource (file path in this case) based on the JobParameter (e.g., date) provided during the job execution.

Answer (score -1):

This could be an easier manner to do it:

```
@Configuration
@Setter
@StepScope
public  class Reader extends FlatFileItemReader<Object> {

public Reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['filePath']}") String resource){
    setResource(new FileSystemResource(resource));
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **StepExecution** context inside a method annotated with `@BeforeStep` annotation inside your item reader to get the Job parameters & set it to a variable, which you can use inside your **read** method.

In my case I've written something like this :-

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpelItemReader implements ItemReader<BatchRequest>{

private String requestId;


@Override
public BatchRequest read() {
   //access the request-id variable here
}

@BeforeStep
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    requestId = stepExecution.getJobParameters().getString("requestId");
}
```

}

Answer (score -3):

Did you declare the jobparameters as map properly as bean?

Or did you perhaps accidently instantiate a [JobParameters](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.html) object, which has no getter for the filename?

For more on expression language you can find information in Spring documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef).