# How to access jobParameters in SpringBatch as a bean?

Tags: spring-batch

I have created jobParameter bean definition like below :

```
<bean id="executionContext" class="com.test.ExecutionContextImpl" scope="step" >
    <property name="toDate" value="#{jobParameters['toDate']}"  />
    <property name="fromDate" value="#{jobParameters['fromDate']}"  />
</bean>
```

and I am using the bean while defining reader like:

```
<bean id="fileDownloadReader" class="com.test.FileDownloadReader"  scope="step" >
    <property name="execCtx" ref="executionContext" />
</bean>
```

While invoking the job from command line am getting below exception.

**with scope=step (in bean definition):**

```
2013/07/01 08-52-19,057:OUT:ERROR[Encountered an error executing the step]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.fileDownloadReader' defined in class path resource [launch-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'com.test.components.TestBean' for property 'reconBean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.test.components.TestBean] for property 'reconBean': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:182)
    at $Proxy17.beforeStep(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeStepExecutionListener.beforeStep(CompositeStepExecutionListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:191)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:349)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'com.test.components.TestBean' for property 'reconBean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.test.components.TestBean] for property 'reconBean': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:465)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:496)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1437)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.test.components.ShipmentReconBean] for property 'reconBean': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:450)
    ... 29 more
2013/07/01 08-52-19,057:ERR:ERROR[Encountered an error executing the step]

[org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean threw org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.fileDownloadReader' defined in class path resource [launch-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'com.test.components.TestBean' for property 'reconBean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.test.components.TestBean] for property 'reconBean': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
2013/07/01 08-52-19,098:OUT:ERROR[Exception in afterStep callback]

[org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean threw org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.fileDownloadReader' defined in class path resource [launch-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'com.test.components.TestBean' for property 'reconBean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.test.components.TestBean] for property 'reconBean': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
2013/07/01 08-52-19,098:ERR:ERROR[Exception in afterStep callback]

[org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean threw org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.fileDownloadReader' defined in class path resource [launch-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'com.test.components.TestBean' for property 'reconBean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.test.components.TestBean] for property 'reconBean': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
Batch Execution Failed!
```

**Without scope = step:**

```
    2013/06/30 14-17-32,299:OUT:ERROR[Job Terminated in error: Error creating bean with name 'fileDownloadReader' defined in class path resource [launch-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext']
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileDownloadReader' defined in class path resource [launch-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:282)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:183)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:246)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:107)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:48)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:93)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:139)
    ... 18 more
```

Any idea how can I get rid of this exception.

Comment: Did you already see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078009/how-to-get-access-to-job-parameters-from-itemreader-in-spring-batch)? Does it help for your problem.

Comment: I tried those already. But could not able to figure out the root cause.

Comment: The exception is saying it's trying to cast an object into your `reconBean` property but can't. Where is `reconBean` in your configuration?

Comment: Why are you passing executionContext this way? Aren't you supposed to use ItemStream? I'm thinking that it has to do with scope="step" because the objects are proxied.

Comment: Could you solve this issue?

Comment: The stacktrace indicate a problem with the wrong type of bean being injected.  Your jobParameters are probably loaded correctly.  i guess your FileDownloadReader is a custom impl of ItemReader?  Instead of assigning your custom executionContext in the XMl, you could @autowired it in your custom Reader.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates something different.

```
Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy13 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.test.components.TestBean] for property 'reconBean': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

I think the problem is somewhere else and not by accessing to the job parameters.

P.S: Can you show the configuration where you define TestBean and set it's property reconBean?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before - there is something creating an AOP proxy that the classloader is using instead of the concrete implementation of your class.  I've solved this in the past by introducing an interface, then calling your getBean as follows:

```
FileDownloadReadable fileDownloadReader = applicationContext.getBean("fileDownloadReader", FileDownloadReadable.class);
```