# Spring Batch Passing list of values as a parameter

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to pass list of id's as one of parameter to Spring batch. Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

From the [JobParameter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameter.html) doc:

> Domain representation of a parameter to a batch job. Only the
>   following types can be parameters: String, Long, Date, and Double. The
>   identifying flag is used to indicate if the parameter is to be used as
>   part of the identification of a job instance.

You might be tempted write your list of of id's to a comma delimited string and pass that as a single parameter but beware that when stored in the DB it [has a length of at most 250 bytes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html). You'll either have to increase that limit or use another way.

Perhaps you can explain what why you need to pass that list of ids.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass the list from `ItemReader`, then you have to get `JobParameters` first (you have to declare your reader to be step scoped for that, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078009/how-to-get-access-to-job-parameters-from-itemreader-in-spring-batch) also).

You will have to put your list as a parameter to the JobParameters. As JobParameters is immutable, you will have to create a new object then

```
List yourList = ....   
JobParameters jp = (JobParameters) fac.getBean("params");
Map map=params.getParameters();
map.put("yourList", list);
params=new JobParameters(map);
launcher.run(job, params);
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use the `List<T>` concept itself in spring-batch, but I think you can implement your intentions(`listOf(a, b, c, d..)`) in the following way.

**The job parameter itself receives a comma-separated string of items.**

```java
@Nonnull
private List<String> someList = Collections.emptyList();

@Value("#{jobParameters['someList']}")
public void setTableNames(@Nullable final String someList) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(tableNames)) {
        this.someList = Arrays.stream(StringUtils.split(someList, ","))
                .map(String::trim)
                .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Hope it was helpful for using list-type parameters in spring-batch!
Thanks.