# how to i pass String array of values as jobParameter into my JobProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to pass an array of String values, like this: `String[] countries = {"IN","BR","CO"};`   My job launcher looks like this:

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] springConfig  = 
        {   "spring/batch/config/database.xml", 
            "spring/batch/config/context.xml",
            "spring/batch/jobs/job-report.xml" 
        };
    ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("blueReportJob");
    try {
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("*** END");
}
```

}

Comment: I want my Process step to have a list of countries that that I should filter out.   I was trying to setup the JobParameters with that list, but maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you shouldn't be using `JobParameters` since those are meant for some other use case.

I didn't found it clearly written on Spring Websites so quoting from [here](http://malsolo.com/blog4java/?p=260)

> JobParameters: a set of parameters used to start a batch job. It
>   categorizes each JobInstance.

i.e. `JobParameters` class is meant to distinguish among various job instances and that is very much a Spring Batch meta data concern.

The data that you are talking about ( list of countries ) seems application logic data ( since you mentioned to use in application processor ) , I would suggest to make it available via other ways - as part of application bootstrapping.

Traditionally, we use application properties, hard coded constants ( lists , maps etc ) , values from files, databases , command line parameters etc etc to provide data to application logic. You should use one of those ways instead of `JobParameters` .

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862027/jobparameters-from-spring-batch) might help if choosing parameter way anyhow.