# Best way to access StepExecution/JobExecution in ItemReader/Processor/Writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I've been using SpringBatch for a few months now..
I used to store execution-related variables(like page count, item count, current position of a batch and so on) into Beans. Then those beans are mounted onto `ItemReader`, `ItemProcessor`, `ItemWriter` by using `setVar()`, `getVar()`-setters and getters. Also those beans are shared among threads with manual synchronization.

But now I found out this could be a wrong way of doing batch jobs. Beans mounted to `ItemReaders` can't be persistent in `JobRepository` and therefore unable to record states for stopping and restarting of a Job. So I still need to go back and use `StepExecution`/`JobExecution`.
Those examples I found online are all based on either XML config, or the worse SpEL autowired to a setter method..

I use purely Java Config..Is there a Java config or Java code-oriented way of accessing `StepExecution`? What's the best practice for accessing various sorts of `ExecutionContext`?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078009/how-to-get-access-to-job-parameters-from-itemreader-in-spring-batch?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

To get access to the `StepExecution` and the `JobExecution` your `ItemReader`, `ItemProcessor`, or `ItemWriter` will have to implement the `StepExecutionListener`.

For instance:

```java
public class MyCustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Object>, StepExecutionListener {

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return stepExecution.getExitStatus();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Object> list) throws Exception {
        if (null == list || list.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot write null or empty list");
        }
        ExecutionContext stepExecContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext()
        ExecutionContext jobExecContext = this.stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
        // TODO: Write your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for partition step. The writer always get a same step execution context

Answer (score 1):

To get access to `StepExecution`, `JobExecution`, you can use methods with annotations from package `org.springframework.batch.core.annotation` or implementing iterfaces like `JobExecutionListener`, `StepExecutionListener` depending on your needs