# How can I use session scoped bean into the batch processing

Tags: java, spring, session

I have created following class

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ApplicationUserInfo implements Serializable {
    private String  user;
    private Integer companynumber;
}
```

I am ding @Autowire to use this class into my Batch processing which is outside the session.
I want to use session scoped bean outside the session so how could I do this?
Is there any other way to use that bean.

Please suggest me.

Comment: What you mean outside of session? Because until the whole flow of the request response is completed it is considered as one session.

Comment: When job will schedule we don't know so before scheduling this job I have to access that bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the session info as a job parameter on start (where the session exists) and then access the parameter [e.g. from reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078009/how-to-get-access-to-job-parameters-from-itemreader-in-spring-batch)

```
JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("user", sessionInfo.getUser())
                .toJobParameters();
```

...

```
jobLauncher.run(yourJob, params);
```

And to get the info in the reader

```
@Value("#{jobParameters['user']}")
```

Comment: How to set values back in the session scoped bean from the job running in batch